# What api to use when getting Microsoft 365 subscription price (i.e Office 365 Business Essentials - $6 / per user per month)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on an application that will try to calculate a customers annual cost base on his/her office 365 subscription, so far I am able to retrieve the customer's subscription using this api

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscribedSkus`

Sample response:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscribedSkus",
"value": [
    {
        "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
        "consumedUnits": 10,
        "id": "db832e68-9b3c-4322-befc-2a864ba73551_3b555118-da6a-4418-894f-7df1e2096870",
        "skuId": "3b555118-da6a-4418-894f-7df1e2096870",
        "skuPartNumber": "O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS",
        "appliesTo": "User",
        "prepaidUnits": {
            "enabled": 10,
            "suspended": 0,
            "warning": 0
        },
        "servicePlans": [
            {
                "servicePlanId": "54fc630f-5a40-48ee-8965-af0503c1386e",
                "servicePlanName": "KAIZALA_O365_P2",
                "provisioningStatus": "PendingProvisioning",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "3c53ea51-d578-46fa-a4c0-fd0a92809a60",
                "servicePlanName": "STREAM_O365_SMB",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "c63d4d19-e8cb-460e-b37c-4d6c34603745",
                "servicePlanName": "OFFICEMOBILE_SUBSCRIPTION",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "5e62787c-c316-451f-b873-1d05acd4d12c",
                "servicePlanName": "BPOS_S_TODO_1",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "159f4cd6-e380-449f-a816-af1a9ef76344",
                "servicePlanName": "FORMS_PLAN_E1",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "0f9b09cb-62d1-4ff4-9129-43f4996f83f4",
                "servicePlanName": "FLOW_O365_P1",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "92f7a6f3-b89b-4bbd-8c30-809e6da5ad1c",
                "servicePlanName": "POWERAPPS_O365_P1",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "57ff2da0-773e-42df-b2af-ffb7a2317929",
                "servicePlanName": "TEAMS1",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "b737dad2-2f6c-4c65-90e3-ca563267e8b9",
                "servicePlanName": "PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "a23b959c-7ce8-4e57-9140-b90eb88a9e97",
                "servicePlanName": "SWAY",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "882e1d05-acd1-4ccb-8708-6ee03664b117",
                "servicePlanName": "INTUNE_O365",
                "provisioningStatus": "PendingActivation",
                "appliesTo": "Company"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014",
                "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTWAC",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "7547a3fe-08ee-4ccb-b430-5077c5041653",
                "servicePlanName": "YAMMER_ENTERPRISE",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "9aaf7827-d63c-4b61-89c3-182f06f82e5c",
                "servicePlanName": "EXCHANGE_S_STANDARD",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "0feaeb32-d00e-4d66-bd5a-43b5b83db82c",
                "servicePlanName": "MCOSTANDARD",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            },
            {
                "servicePlanId": "c7699d2e-19aa-44de-8edf-1736da088ca1",
                "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTSTANDARD",
                "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                "appliesTo": "User"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

but I am not able to retrieve the subscription cost. I tried to scan through all of microsoft graph api reference but to no avail.
Is there a way for me to retrieve the cost of a subscription from microsoft graph api or are there any other api's i need to call?.

Comment: A tip... don't put "P.S this is a huge feature for the application we are buidling."  It has the exact opposite effect you're trying to achieve.  All a statement like that does is generally make us *not* want to answer your question.  Stack Overflow isn't free consulting, and shouldn't be treated as such.

Comment: sorry about that @Brad, It's my first time asking here, I removed it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the azure [Usage Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails) API for your requirement. 
No graph api for this now, if you still want to use graph API, submit one feature request on the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: thanks but i ran through the documentation and it seems to only show you azure subscription usage and not office 365 subscription, is that correct?